# Some apps (SD card ones?) not restored after factory reset of S5. What have I lost? Help!

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-5

After a factory reset of my Galaxy S5(same accounts and sim etc), some apps did not restore. I suspect it was the large ones I had moved to the SD card a while back for space reasons (I took my SD card out during the reset and restore process).

Looking in my files>SD card>android>data, there are plenty of apps that did get restored that have files on SD card, but it helped me pinpoint a few that didn't reappear. For example Excel. I then checked the app manager and there aren't there under SD card (though I might be confusing the inbuilt and external SD card).

On Play store>my apps & games, they obviously aren't under 'installed', nor even under 'Library', nor when i search for them individually do the paid versions show as already paid...

I synced my backups on google and Samsung accounts directly before the factory reset

My questions then are:
- Where can i find out what I've lost? ie a list of apps as of yesterday
- Is there any way of restoring apps moved to SD card?
- If not, I might as well wipe the pre-reset data folder on SD-card, right?
- What is likely to have happened?
- Before any future factory resets, should i move everything important back to phone before syncing and resetting

Thank you for your time and expertise!!!